# First website, Uploaded default.html but not showing

Tags: php, html, indexing

i am new in web designing and learning working with HTML. i just uploaded a page to hosting panel. but its just showing a page "index of/" how ever i tried even uploading a single page html file. but not working. can anyone please guide where i am mistaking?
here is the link http://whatsapphubstatus.com
and the code i used on index.html is

```html
<h1>This is My First Website </h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your

```
index..html
```

to

```
index.html
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change file name from `index..html` to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

index..html change file name to index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo with the file name. It should be index.html instead of index..html.